# C++ undefined symbol

Tags: c++, file-io, istream, ostream

I am creating a C++ console application where I am saving and loading a vector to a file. The file I am saving and loading has a header that has the size of the vector.

Here is my code:

```
void loadFromFile()
    {
        ifstream iStream("file.ext", ios::binary);
        fileHeader_t fHeader;
        iStream.read((char*)&fHeader, sizeof(fileHeader_t));
        if (fHeader.magicNumber = 0xDEADBEAF)
        {
            appointments.resize(fHeader.appointmentCount); iStream.read((char*)&appointments[0], fHeader.appointmentCount * sizeof(appointment));
        }
    }
    void saveToFile()
    {
        ofstream oStream("file.ext", ios::binary);
        fileHeader_t fHeader;
        fHeader.magicNumber = 0xDEADBEAF;
        fHeader.appointmentCount = appointments.size();
        oStream.write((char*)&fHeader, sizeof(fileHeader_t));
        oStream.write((char*)&appointments[0], sizeof(appointment) * appointments.size());
    }
```

And here is the header struct:

```
struct fileHeader_s
{
DWORD magicNumber;
size_t appointmentsCount;
}fileHeader_t;
```

I am getting the following errors:

> E2379 Statement missing ;
>   E2451 Undefined symbol 'fHeader'

At the following lines:

```
fileHeader_t fHeader;
```

Why is this happening, and more importantly, how can I fix it?

Thanks

**Update**

Here is my full code:

```
class appointment
{
public:
    appointment(string aDate, string aTime, string aType,
    string aLocation, string aComments, bool aIsImportant,
    string aReminderDate, string aReminderTime)
    {
        appDate = aDate;
        appTime = aTime;
        appType = aType;
        appLocation = aLocation;
        appComments = aComments;
        appIsImportant = aIsImportant;
        appReminderDate = aReminderDate;
        appReminderTime = aReminderTime;
    }
    void setDate(string aDate)
    {
        appDate = aDate;
    }
    void setTime(string aTime)
    {
        appTime = aTime;
    }
    void setType(string aType)
    {
        appType = aType;
    }
    void setLocation(string aLocation)
    {
        appLocation = aLocation;
    }
    void setComments(string aComments)
    {
        appComments = aComments;
    }
    void setIsImportant(bool aIsImportant)
    {
        appIsImportant = aIsImportant;
    }
    void setReminderDate(string aReminderDate)
    {
        appReminderDate = aReminderDate;
    }
    void setReminderTime(string aReminderTime)
    {
        appReminderTime = aReminderTime;
    }
    string getDate()
    {
        return appDate;
    }
    string getTime()
    {
        return appTime;
    }
    string getType()
    {
        return appType;
    }
    string getLocation()
    {
        return appLocation;
    }
    string getComments()
    {
        return appComments;
    }
    bool getIsImportant()
    {
        return appIsImportant;
    }
    string getReminderDate()
    {
        return appReminderDate;
    }
    string getReminderTime()
    {
        return appReminderTime;
    }
private:
    appointment();
    string appDate;
    string appTime;
    string appType;
    string appLocation;
    string appComments;
    bool appIsImportant;
    string appReminderDate;
    string appReminderTime;
    //person owner;
};

class calendar
{
public:
    calendar()
    {
        loadFromFile();
    }
    ~calendar()
    {
        saveToFile();
    }

    void createAppointment(string aDate, string aTime, string aType, string aLocation, string aComments, bool aIsImportant, string aReminderDate, string aReminderTime)
    {
        appointment newAppointment(aDate, aTime, aType, aLocation, aComments, aIsImportant, aReminderDate, aReminderTime);
        appointments.push_back(newAppointment);
    }

private:
    vector<appointment> appointments;
    string calCurrentDate;
    string calCurrentTime;
    void loadFromFile()
    {
        ifstream iStream("file.ext", ios::binary);
        fileHeader_t fHeader;
        iStream.read((char*)&fHeader, sizeof(fileHeader_t));
        if (fHeader.magicNumber = 0xDEADBEAF)
        {
            appointments.resize(fHeader.appointmentCount); iStream.read((char*)&appointments[0], fHeader.appointmentCount * sizeof(appointment));
        }
    }
    void saveToFile()
    {
        ofstream oStream("file.ext", ios::binary);
        fileHeader_t fHeader;
        fHeader.magicNumber = 0xDEADBEAF;
        fHeader.appointmentCount = appointments.size();
        oStream.write((char*)&fHeader, sizeof(fileHeader_t));
        oStream.write((char*)&appointments[0], sizeof(appointment) * appointments.size());
    }
    typedef struct fileHeader_s
    {
        DWORD magicNumber;
        size_t appointmentCount;
    }fileHeader_t;
};
```

I am getting the following 2 errors:

[BCC32 Warning] Person.cpp(271): W8060 Possibly incorrect assignment
  Full parser context
    Person.cpp(245): class calendar
    Person.cpp(290): decision to instantiate: void calendar::loadFromFile()
    --- Resetting parser context for instantiation...
    Person.cpp(267): parsing: void calendar::loadFromFile()

[BCC32 Error] vector(608): E2247 'appointment::appointment()' is not accessible
  Full parser context
    vector(607): decision to instantiate: void vector >::resize(unsigned int)
    --- Resetting parser context for instantiation...
    Person.cpp(18): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\9.0\include\dinkumware\vector
    vector(8): namespace std
    vector(330): class vector<_Ty,_Ax>
    vector(607): parsing: void vector >::resize(unsigned int)

Can I please have some help to fix this?

Comment: You forgot the `struct`.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question. Can I please have some help?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek: HINT: The problem is `private: appointment();`.

Comment: In the appointment class? I wanted to make it private there so that when the object is created, the values HAVE to be entered in. Should I not do this when using vectors and saving/loading to files?

Comment: OK, I have changed the value to public... now I am getting the following errors: [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'appointment::appointment()' referenced from H:\2012\TRIMESTER 2\IT6253 - C++ PROGRAMMING\ASSESSMENT 2\WIN32\DEBUG\PERSON.OBJ and [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link

Comment: @DarrylJanecek: When you resize the vector, how are you thinking the new appointments will be created? What constructor is there that could be used?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek: Thats because you never defined `appointment::appointment()`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: There are two constructors, default and paramaterized. I thought that the code I have basically gets the appointment vector that is saved to a file, with all its details, and basically loads this data into a vector, without having to call any constructors at all. Do I have this wrong? Does the constructor still need to be called in the Appointment class? If so, I would like to call the paramaterized constructor with the details from the file... yet, how do I separate each value from the file to then use the paramaterized constrcutor?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek: Where's the default constructor for `appointment`? You say there is one and that it's private, but the code for it never actually appears. Without it, how can you `resize` the vector?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the typedef keyword in struct definition.

```
typedef struct fileHeader_s
{

}fileHeader_t;
```

However, in C++ it is not required for the typedef keyword. In that case, struct name is still `fileHeader_s`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a `typedef`

```
typedef struct fileHeader_s
{
DWORD magicNumber;
size_t appointmentsCount;
}fileHeader_t;
```